# Pandas indexing, searching in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

**Problem solved**

Using `loc` istead of `iloc` solves the problem but I'm not sure why.

---

Medium size of dataframe (80766, 19), composed of ints, floats and dates.
While my work, I noticed my results were strange.
I started transforming and simplifying expressions to see where the problem was, and came into a contradiction.

Using these two lines I got the same result (as expected):

```
import pandas
...
data_table[data_table[col_name] == 69][col_name]
data_table.iloc[data_table.index[data_table[col_name] == 69]][col_name]
```

Result:

```
23270    69
23271    69
         ..
25059    69
Name: BBCH, Length: 1790, dtype: int64
```

But when I changed the searched value for higher, the second line gives a completely incorrect result.

```
data_table[data_table[col_name] == 71][col_name]
```

Gives good result:

```
39556    71
39557    71
         ..
41353    71
Name: BBCH, Length: 1798, dtype: int64
```

And for

```
data_table.iloc[data_table.index[data_table[col_name] == 71]][col_name]
```

the result is:

```
7336    30
7337    30
        ..
9133    30
Name: BBCH, Length: 1798, dtype: int64
```

My question is why is it that? Is it a problem with size of data?

Comment: Could it be that you need `loc` instead of `iloc`?

Comment: @fsimonjetz Thanks a lot. Using loc solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your index is a `RangeIndex`, i.e., has no gaps, you can use `loc` and `iloc` interchangeably, e.g.,

```py
>>> s = pd.Series('foo', index=range(10))
>>> s
0    foo
1    foo
2    foo
3    foo
4    foo
5    foo
6    foo
7    foo
8    foo
9    foo
dtype: object
>>> s.loc[[1, 2, 7]]
1    foo
2    foo
7    foo
dtype: object
>>> s.iloc[[1, 2, 7]]
1    foo
2    foo
7    foo
dtype: object
```

But `s.loc[[1, 2, 7]]` selects the rows that are *labelled* `1`, `2`, and `7`, no matter their position, while `iloc` extracts the rows that are at the *positional* indices `1`, `2`, and `7`. If you changed the order of the rows in `s`, `loc` would still give the same rows, but `iloc` would give whatever ends up at the second, third, and 8th row.

If you modify your data so that it's no longer a `RangeIndex` (i.e., there are rows missing if you will), `loc` and `iloc` will give different result once they select something that follows a "missing row". Hence in the example below, with the modified `s`, the rows at index `1` and `2` are still labelled as `1` and `2`, so they are selected by both `loc` and `iloc`, but the 8th row is no longer labelled `7`, but `9` (as we removed two rows in the middle).

```py
>>> s = s.drop([3, 4])
>>> s
0    foo # position = 0
1    foo # 1
2    foo # 2
5    foo # 3 but label == 5!!
6    foo # 4 but label == 6
7    foo # etc.
8    foo
9    foo
dtype: object
>>> s.loc[[1, 2, 7]]
1    foo
2    foo
7    foo
dtype: object
>>> s.iloc[[1, 2, 7]]
1    foo
2    foo
9    foo # != 7 !!
dtype: object
```

That explains why in the first case, your result was correct, but in the second case, something caused the labels of the index to be "out of sync" with the positional values (probably some dropped rows). As you selected by subsetting the *labels* of `.index`, you need `loc`, not `iloc`. (If you did a `reset_index` before subsetting, `iloc` would work again, because then the index would again be identical to the positions of the rows.)

Comment: Your explanation describes exactly what happened in my code. Just before this, I deleted some items from the table.